# Should I edit my (long existing, highly upvoted) closed question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31412537/numpy-like-package-for-node/49213594#49213594) 8 years ago, and over 6 years it received 91 upvotes. Then two years ago the question was closed for being opinion-based. I don't agree that it is, but that's not my issue. I do agree that the question and many of it's answers are out-of-date by now.

What bothers me is that the close message invites me to take one of two actions: edit the question or delete it, and I'm not sure what I should do here. I can certainly edit the question, including all the insights I have on the issue now (8 years later), which may even return it to an acceptable question for SO. However it would mean that all the answers (top one with 42 upvotes) do not make sense anymore.

I guess deleting the question would also be a shame, since (considering how many people found it useful), it does contain useful information.

So I would love to hear what would be the best step for me to take?

[image: close message]

Comment: I don't think you have to do anything. Closed questions can still be useful, either for the information within, or as a signpost to something else. If the material is useful don't delete it. Edits are fine in general but, as you say, you don't want to invalidate an answer.

Comment: (By the by, I wonder if the close reason should have been "Recommendations" rather than Opinion Based, but that may not be terribly important).

Comment: Can this be migrated to meta.so? It doesn't belong here.

Comment: @IanKemp You can flag it asking for migration.

Comment: @halfer Technically, recommendation questions *are* primarily based on opinions. The separate close reason is simply so authors are directed to more specific resources in that case.